# Wok slides around in ring

Tags: equipment, asian-cuisine, wok

I have a round bottom wok with a metal handle. When placed in the wok ring, the wok slides down to the handle side due to the weight. The ring is reversible, however it slides on either side. This is so annoying. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Did the ring come with the wok?

Comment: No. they were not. The wok was given to me from a closing restaurant. The ring was from another wok set.

Comment: I'm not a wok expert so I won't put this as an answer. My instinct would be to modify the inside of the ring so that there are small protrusions that stick out and grip the sides. The problem with that is if it doesn't work you've ruined your wok ring. However, there may be better answers. It could be that the wok is designed to work with a specific ring.

Comment: Yes I agree. I am hoping that there may be someone with some experience in solving this issue. In an Asian kitchen, this wok  would mostly likely sit lower in the a ring or the stove itself accepts the wok in its top. With our traditional stoves, we need a ring or some custom devise. If all else fails, I will have to give up this wok for a new flat bottom wok.

Comment: The wok ring that came with my stove does that.  It's better to just do without in my case, as my wok has a slightly flattened bottom (but the big burner is also pretty rubbish with a wok as the flame ring is too wide).

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a fix…just add food to the wok.  In most cases the added weight of the food will balance the weight of the handle.  I don’t really find the position an issue, it just means that the handle gets a bit hotter than the other side.  I always have a dry towel to handle the metal wok handle while cooking.

It doesn’t affect the food, as when you start to use the wok you will lift the handle and it will be level.  Another option is just to use a Cantonese style wok with the double ears, they don’t have the lopsided handle on one side, so it doesn’t have the problem.

Alternatively, if it really bothers you, you can rest the wok handle on another pan or pot so that it sits properly in the wok ring.  The other pot or pan will be off to the left side if you use that hand for the wok, or vise versa if you are using your right hand.  But usually just adding your food will be enough to correct it.